# Join between two rows depend on other row, using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

For each two rows I have same "id"/num, and I need to get all num that their state is 0 in 2 row.

For example like in my table the result will be:

> num : 2, 3

because for num 2 the state for type a is 0 and the state for type b is 0 also. But num 1 have 1 in type b so it is not good.

How I do this with SQL query or with JSON data or array in PHP? My table is:

```
id | num | type  |state 
1  | 1   | a     | 0 
2  | 1   | b     | 1
3  | 2   | a     | 0
4  | 2   | b     | 0
5  | 3   | a     | 0
6  | 3   | b     | 0
```

Comment: How about `SELECT DISTINCT num FROM t WHERE state = 0 AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM t WHERE state = 1)`?

Comment: (To start solving this problem, of course you should create a MySQL database/table, enter the data, and start playing around with queries. If the above suggestion doesn't work exactly -- I have not tested it -- tweak it until it does).

Comment: @halfer  - it is not return me the num like i want, i need  : 2,3  because  num 1 have row with state 1

Comment: Ah yes, I can see how that would not work. Alright, well you have several answers now. I would reiterate the usual advice here about setting up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), so you/we can easily test your data scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can give this a try:

```
SELECT
  num
FROM myTable
GROUP BY num
HAVING sum(state) = 0
```

Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e54cc/3).

Comment: thanks it is work , can you explain me how it is work ?

Comment: @tzwx2010 Simple group by with aggregate in having.

Answer (score 0):

A self join without a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.num
from tablexxx t1
join tablexxx t2
on t2.num=t1.num
and t2.state=0 and t1.state=0
```

Add an index on `num` (perhaps).

Comment: can you add the query please?